# Rolling a dice until we get a 5 or a 6

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have some trouble with this problem:

I keep tossing a fair six-sided dice until I get a 5 or a 6. Let **T** be the number of times I roll the dice and **X** the result of the last toss that I do.

1. What is the value of $\Bbb{P}(T=3, X=5)$?
2. find the distribution of **T**
3. find the distribution of **X**
4. Are **X** and **T** independent?

For the first point I think that is $\Bbb{P}(T=3, X=5)$ = $(\frac46) (\frac46) (\frac26$) and I tried to do the second one in this way: $P(T=k)=(\frac23)^{k-1}(\frac13)$ , where $(\frac23)^{k-1}$ means that the first $k−1$ rolls of the dice gave a number other than 5 or 6, and the **k**th roll gave exacly 5 or 6. 
From now on I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

$P(T=3, X = 5) = \left(\frac {4}{6}\right)\left(\frac {4}{6}\right)\left(\frac {1}{6}\right)$

Answer to the second question is correct.

The distriubtion of $x.$

$P(X=k)= \begin{cases} \frac 12 & k \in \{5,6\}\\ 0 & k\notin\{5,6\}\end{cases}$

Are they independent?  Should it matter how many times you rolled the dice whether you roll a $5$ or a $6$ on your next roll?